# Speech to text on two streams using Nodejs

Tags: node.js, google-api-nodejs-client, google-cloud-speech

I'm trying to run Speech to text on two streams - one from the mic and one from the speaker.

I have it conceptually figured out but am stuck on these two points:

1. combining mic & speaker streams into one stream
2. sending combined stream

For problem 1, I think I can use SoX or FFMPEG to combine the two mono streams into a single stream with two channels.

For problem 2, I'm thinking of pipe-ing the combined stream to the recognizer (as in the [infinite streaming sample](https://github.com/googleapis/nodejs-speech/blob/master/samples/infiniteStreaming.js))

Has anyone worked on a problem like this? Could this work?

Comment: how exactly did you separate the speaker and microphone streams? I am looking into this ATM not can't find much information.